# Extract and Trust certificate via command line in windows

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

I am trying to setup a printer via command line in windows. So far I everything is working well except I don't know of any way to extract .cer from .cat via command line.

I could extract it via windows gui and later successfully trust it via certmgr.exe.

So if anyone knows how or can point me in the direction of extracting .cer from .cat using command line.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Thanks. There is quite a grey line between devops and pure dev. Anyways I posted the question in super user.